# Select one item from array rather than repeat through

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

When I use an ng-repeat I loop through the array and spit it all out, however I want to use the same datasource as soemthign else and only have one of them selected.

Rather than use ng-repeat and filter to just the one record I assume there must be a better way.

```
 .controller('ViewBarsCtrl', function ($scope) {
        $scope.bars = [
            { title: 'Toms Bar', id: 1, strapline: "Potential Strapline?", picture: "img/test/pub.jpg" },
            { title: 'Haydens Bar', id: 2, strapline: "Potential Strapline?", picture: "img/test/pub.jpg" },
            { title: 'Jackis Jaunt', id: 3, strapline: "Potential Strapline?", picture: "img/test/pub.jpg" },
            { title: 'Alans Place ', id: 4, strapline: "Potential Strapline?", picture: "img/test/pub.jpg" },
            { title: 'Harveys Local', id: 5, strapline: "Potential Strapline?", picture: "img/test/pub.jpg" },
            { title: 'Mitchells Spot', id: 6, strapline: "Potential Strapline?", picture: "img/test/pub.jpg" }
        ];
    })
```

That's my controller. I'vv got BarID coming in through state params so I want to select the row that's right for the BarID and be able to do like `{{$scope.bar.title}}` in my html

Comment: can you display your code properly. I can't seem to edit your question

Comment: You'll have to filter either in the view (with `ng-repeat`) or in the controller with `.filter`.  The performance will probably be slightly better in the controller.

Comment: Sorry my mistake  tommy. Ah Davin, is that so? I assumed there would be a more efficient way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop through the bars, match the id, and assign that bar to a new variable:

```
var id = idYouGotFromState;
for (var i = 0; i < $scope.bars.length; i++) {
    if ($scope.bars[i].id === id) {
        $scope.bar = $scope.bars[i];
        break;
    }
}
```

Then you'd be able to use `{{bar.title}}` just fine.

---

See it here:

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('ViewBarsCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.bars = [
        { title: 'Toms Bar', id: 1, strapline: "Potential Strapline?", picture: "img/test/pub.jpg" },
        { title: 'Haydens Bar', id: 2, strapline: "Potential Strapline?", picture: "img/test/pub.jpg" },
        { title: 'Jackis Jaunt', id: 3, strapline: "Potential Strapline?", picture: "img/test/pub.jpg" },
        { title: 'Alans Place ', id: 4, strapline: "Potential Strapline?", picture: "img/test/pub.jpg" },
        { title: 'Harveys Local', id: 5, strapline: "Potential Strapline?", picture: "img/test/pub.jpg" },
        { title: 'Mitchells Spot', id: 6, strapline: "Potential Strapline?", picture: "img/test/pub.jpg" }
    ];

    var id = 2;
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.bars.length; i++) {
      if ($scope.bars[i].id === id) {
        $scope.bar = $scope.bars[i];
        break;
      }
    }
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ViewBarsCtrl">
  Bar: {{bar.title}}
  </div>
```

Comment: Ah that seems a good idea. Strange one here though, I have     var id = $stateParams.barID; and when i do a log on that it says 2 however it doesn't ever find a match in the loop. However, when I manually put a 2 in there instead of stateParams it works

Comment: Changed from === to == fixed that

Comment: Yes, either == or do `parseInt` to make sure it's an integer.